# Select option and Popover - Always getting the last selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

**This is my code select option and popover using html and jquery**

**Problem:** When I select an option, its working but when i select another option it's always getting the last selected value.

**Ex.** If I select Name of Game 4 - 
the value for a href link must be name4

https://www.mygames.com/restore/accept/'+value+
https://www.mygames.com/restore/accept/name4

but when i select another option like Name of Game 7
it will get the last value which is name4 and it must be game7

```
//Selection
$('#mygame').change(function() {
  var value = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

  //Restore
  $('.restore').popover({
    trigger: 'focusin',
    html:true,
    placement:'bottom',
    title:'Restore Folder',
    content:'<a href="https://www.mygames.com/restore/accept/'+value+'" target="_blank" class ="btn btn-info btn-sm">Accept</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.mygames.com/restore/review/'+value+'"  target="_blank" class ="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Review</a>'
  });   

  //Backup
  $('.backup').popover({
    trigger: 'focusin',
    html:true,
    placement:'bottom',
    title:'Backup Folder',
    content:'<a href="https://www.mygames.com/backup/accept/'+value+'" target="_blank" class ="btn btn-info btn-sm">Accept</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.mygames.com/backup/review/'+value+'"  target="_blank" class ="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Review</a>'
  });   

});
```

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div style="padding-bottom:10px;">
  <select name="mygame" id="mygame" style="width:16em;">
    <option value="choose">-- Choose Game --</option>
    <option value="name1">Name of Game 1</option>
    <option value="name2">Name of Game 2</option>
    <option value="name3">Name of Game 3</option>
    <option value="name4">Name of Game 4</option>
    <option value="name5">Name of Game 5</option>
    <option value="name6">Name of Game 6</option>
    <option value="name7">Name of Game 7</option>
    <option value="name8">Name of Game 8</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
  <button class="restore" id="restore">Restore Folder </button>  
  <button class="backup" id="backup">Backup Folder</button>                          
</div>  

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Jsfiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/ud5Lrhwb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of initializing the plugin every time the select changes, use a function for content and get the value of the select in that function and only initialize the plugin once

```js
$('.backup').popover({
  trigger: 'focusin',
  html: true,
  placement: 'bottom',
  title: 'Backup Folder',
  content: function() {
    const value = $('#mygame').val();

    return '<a href="https://www.mygames.com/backup/accept/' + value + '" target="_blank" class ="btn btn-info btn-sm">Accept</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.mygames.com/backup/review/' + value + '"  target="_blank" class ="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Review</a>';
  }
});

$('.restore').popover({
  trigger: 'focusin',
  html: true,
  placement: 'bottom',
  title: 'Restore Folder',
  content: function() {
    const value = $('#mygame').val()

    return '<a href="https://www.mygames.com/restore/accept/' + value + '" target="_blank" class ="btn btn-info btn-sm">Accept</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.mygames.com/restore/review/' + value + '"  target="_blank" class ="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Review</a>'
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="padding-bottom:10px;">
  <select name="mygame" id="mygame" style="width:16em;">
    <option value="choose">-- Choose Game --</option>
    <option value="name1">Name of Game 1</option>
    <option value="name2">Name of Game 2</option>
    <option value="name3">Name of Game 3</option>
    <option value="name4">Name of Game 4</option>
    <option value="name5">Name of Game 5</option>
    <option value="name6">Name of Game 6</option>
    <option value="name7">Name of Game 7</option>
    <option value="name8">Name of Game 8</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
  <button class="restore" id="restore">Restore Folder </button>
  <button class="backup" id="backup">Backup Folder</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```